# Oracle SQL Developer how to dynamicly run sql scripts

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following challange;

I would like to execute a batch of *.sql files on one database. The sql files are assumed to be named in ascending order of their execution sequence. So the main sql script should do a 'dir /s *.sql', then start each of the found scripts in order.

Is this possible ?

Below is something I found for SQL Server, but I want something similar for Oracle SQL Developer.

http://pradeep1210.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/executing-a-set-of-sql-script-files-sql-on-a-group-of-sql-server-databases/

Thanks in advance.

Raymond

Comment: It would be easier to write a shell script that concatenated all your scripts into one SQL file, then run that.

Comment: Why do that with SQL Developer? A simple batch/shell script calling sql*plus seems much more appropriate.

Comment: And keep in mind that the SQL files should be placed on the server side, if you are doing it with an T-SQL script.

Comment: Somehow I don't think the OP will be using a T-SQL script with Oracle.

Comment: And with Oracle you can certainly do it all client side.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a folder for eg:`Batch_Files` in you local machine ,which will contain all the sql script that you want to execute ,
2. Then open you `sql developer` .Create a file called `batch.sql` in your Batch_Files folder .
3. In `Batch.sql` add the sql files that you want to execute in sequence.

   @file1.sql

   @file2.sql
     :

   :

   @fileN.sql

These files contains the code that you need to run in sequence .This is a very basic example.You can do various changes according to your need ,you can add anonymous block to print something after execution of files .I have not tested this is `SQL-DEVELOPER` ,but i think this will surely work for you .