# How to run .sql file in Oracle SQL developer tool to import database?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have exported database from Oracle SQL developer tool into .sql file. Now I want to run this file which is of size 500+ MB.

I read about running scripts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137258/oracle-sql-developer-how-to-dynamicly-run-sql-scripts), but I didn't understand the way. Is there any command or query by which we can run this sql script by providing path?

Comment: How did you export, using `EXPDP`? Is it a dump file or just a .sql file?

Comment: Tool -> Export Database ...   I didn't get any other way

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You could execute the `.sql` file as a script in the **SQL Developer** worksheet. Either use the **Run Script** icon, or simply press <kbd>F5</kbd>.

[image]

For example,

```
@path\script.sql;
```

Remember, you need to put `@` as shown above.

But, if you have exported the database using database export utility of SQL Developer, then you should use the Import utility. Follow the steps mentioned here [Importing and Exporting using the Oracle SQL Developer 3.0](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r30/SQLdev3.0_Import_Export/sqldev3.0_import_export.htm)

Comment: where should I run this command? Because I can get query explorer screen after click on one of present db

Comment: @Rushikesh Open a SQL Worksheet and then do as I said above.

Comment: For me...that Icon is not present :(

Comment: I gave a 12GB .sql file of my whole database and the Oracle SQL Developer just Crashed :(

Comment: @MDaniyal You should consider Datapump import.

Comment: Yes then I used `impdp` to import `.dmp` file. But I really want to know how to convert `.sql` to `.dmp`.

Comment: Dump file can be only created by expdp.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! Works like a charm (example on Windows : `@D:\Scripts\import.sql`)

Comment: If you have spaces in your path use "..." for example: @"c:\temp\big path with spaces\sqltool - oracle.sql"

Answer (score 2):

You need to Open the SQL Developer first and then click on **File** option and browse to the location where your .sql is placed. Once you are at the location where file is placed double click on it, this will get the file open in SQL Developer. Now select all of the content of file **(CTRL + A)** and press **F9** key. Just make sure there is a commit statement at the end of the .sql script so that the changes are persisted in the database

Comment: Unfortunately, when the file is 500+ MB as asked in the question, the SQL developer will fail to open it.

Comment: In my case, the file is 2.5MB, and SQL Developer fails to open it.

Comment: Lalit's answer is the correct one, just make sure you put sufficient commits in your script if it is a very long file. (Provided you are happy committing as you go!!!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Load function

```
Load TableName fullfilepath;
```