# Generate ER diagram from SQL Script

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, entity-relationship

I have some SQL scripts written in a .sql file
I need to generate ER diagram using those scripts, so that I can verify the relationships and then get them executed in the DB.

Can anyone help me on how I can achieve this?
I would prefer doing this in SQLDeveloper

EDIT: As ismetguzelgun suggested me in his answer to execute the scripts first and then export the diagram through data modeler. I do not have the permission to execute DML commands in the Database and I do not have any other database as well where I can execute this. So that option is not going to work out for me.

Comment: You can try first executing your sql code from file(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31560367/how-to-run-sql-file-in-oracle-sql-developer-tool-to-import-database) and get your tables ready then following the instructions here (https://dataedo.com/kb/tools/oracle-sql-developer/create-database-diagram). Other than that as i know of there is no solution directly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated my question based on your previously posted answer. This is not going to work out in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the import feature.

File - Data Modeler - Import - DDL Script

[image]

Point to one or more .sql files.

[image]

A dialogue will appear showing what's about to be added to your design. Make sure everything's checked and hit the Merge button.

[image]

Your new/existing design is ready!

[image]

If you don't see anything in the diagram area, zoom out or use the Navigator window to make sure you're in an area with your tables. Or use the tree on the left, pick a table, and right click, 'Go to Diagram' - it will take you directly to that object in the diagram.

Comment: I did this and got a blank window after merge. I had selected oracle 12c

Comment: Updated my answer @derek. See if that helps.

Comment: Important point is to make sure we zoom out. Thanks a lot! Works like charm.